# How do I list all members in a Launchpad team?

Tags: launchpad, launchpad-api

How can I produce a text file list of all members in Launchpad team?

For example, this page only shows the list of users in batches of 75:
http://launchpad.net/~launchpad-beta-testers/+members

I would like to get the whole list in one text dump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained by @Rinzwind, you'll need to make multiple queries to take into account the pagination or use python and [launchpadlib](https://help.launchpad.net/API/launchpadlib) to handle the pagination for you:

```
>>> team = launchpad.people['launchpad-beta-testers']
>>> len(team.members)
2238
```

Comment: +1 ! cool api :) I just had to steal the link for my own answer >:)

Answer (score 2):

> - Altering the URL

Besides mailing someone to get a list of members I doubt it will be possible to get this list in 1 go. The URL has a parameter in it to expand the amount of names but the maximum amount of members you can get on 1 page is `300`.

https://launchpad.net/~launchpad-beta-testers/+members?active_batch=300

That would make it 8 pages you need to copy/paste. This would be the quickest *1 time usable* solution.

> - alternate solution...

If you can code you could make a script for this. Maybe someone can expand on this:

- `wget https://launchpad.net/~launchpad-beta-testers/+members?active_batch=300 --no-check-certificate` will get the 1st 300.
- `wget https://launchpad.net/~launchpad-beta-testers/+members?active_batch=300&active_memo=300&active_start=300 --no-check-certificate` will get the 2nd 300.
- `wget https://launchpad.net/~launchpad-beta-testers/+members?active_batch=300&active_memo=600&active_start=600 --no-check-certificate` will get the 3rd 300.

With a combination of `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `regexes` and maybe some other tools it should be possible to get the names from commandline.

I download these 3 to 3 text files and the command...

`grep class=\"sprite\ person\"  * |more`

gets me all the lines that have a name in it (with a bit of overhead) for this file.

You can use https://help.launchpad.net/API/launchpadlib for this if you want to code a program for it.